# Image not pulled in systemd ExecStartPre=

Tags: docker, systemd, coreos

I'm getting this message from `systemd/dockerd`:

```
Dec 29 14:41:32 core-01 systemd[1]: Starting ElasticSearch...
Dec 29 14:41:32 core-01 docker[1335]: Error response from daemon: No such container: es
Dec 29 14:41:32 core-01 docker[1346]: Error response from daemon: No such container: es
Dec 29 14:41:33 core-01 docker[1367]: Pulling repository prv.private.registry/elasticsearch-qa
Dec 29 14:41:33 core-01 docker[1367]: Error: image elasticsearch-qa not found
Dec 29 14:41:33 core-01 systemd[1]: living-es.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
```

So it's telling me that `image elasticsearch-qa not found`.

The systemd service definition is:

```
  - name: living-es.service
    command: start
    enable: true
    content: |-
      [Unit]
      Description=ElasticSearch
      Author=Living
      After=docker.service

      [Service]
      Restart=always
      RestartSec=10s
      ExecStartPre=-/usr/bin/docker stop es
      ExecStartPre=-/usr/bin/docker rm es
      ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/docker pull prv.private.registry/elasticsearch-qa:v1
      ExecStart=/usr/bin/docker run --name es -p 9200:9200 -p 9300:9300 --hostname es -v /home/core/data/es:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data prv.private.registry.com/elasticsearch-qa:v1 -Des.node.name="esn1" -Des.cluster.name="cluster"
      ExecStop=/usr/bin/docker stop es
```

The message it's clear, nevertheless, when I pull the image on shell, it's pulled correctly. Any ideas?

```
docker pull prv.private.registry/elasticsearch-qa:v1
v1: Pulling from elasticsearch-qa
8ad8b3f87b37: Pull complete
751fe39c4d34: Pull complete
b165e84cccc1: Pull complete
acfcc7cbc59b: Pull complete
04b7a9efc4af: Pull complete
b16e55fe5285: Pull complete
8c5cbb866b55: Pull complete
53c3dd7fc70d: Pull complete
3de13756a8c8: Pull complete
64be422416b7: Pull complete
b808918635ce: Pull complete
5b3ceec8c156: Pull complete
561269d0b7cc: Pull complete
0c6cf9533753: Pull complete
5234b57e3d12: Pull complete
4a86b042378a: Pull complete
c6f98581a18c: Pull complete
b6ee1115f29d: Pull complete
Digest: sha256:1f3c29d4f10ae897f67067ff72b8e25d8380531f04637941e67747bec96228f9code=exited status=1
Status: Downloaded newer image for prv.private.registry/elasticsearch-qa:v1
```

Comment: Theory: When you are using a registry, you first need to run `docker login` to register with it. That works as your user, but systemd isn't running as your user, it runs probably as root.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try running the `docker pull` command manually as `root`, since that's the user that systemd is running as.  It may fail to authenticate to your private repo because the credentials are stored in your user preferences.

If that's the case, try adding `User=yourusername` to your `systemd` unit file.